# What is the way to run Python code with JSON Parameters in MATLAB?

Tags: python, json, matlab

I am working in ML problem. I create some modules by using python and I need to call these modules in MATLAB.
Those modules are stored in JSON files and they are inputs for Python code like below:

```py
import argparse
import importlib
import json
import os

from simulation import run


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    To run, pass the path to the JSON file as the first (only) parameter.
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="CCO Simulation")
    parser.add_argument(
        "JSON_file",
        metavar="<JSON Parameter File>",
        type=str,
        help="<JSON parameter file>",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(os.path.abspath(args.JSON_file)) as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        run(json_data)
```

When I try to run this file in Python code or MATLAB I get error like this

```
Usage:run [-h] <JSON Parameter File>
run.py: errorr: the following arguments are required: <JSON Parameter File >
```

Please,can you help me to solve this problem and run the code in the right way.

Comment: How do you launch the python file (or in matlab)? The error tells you that it misses the json file argument.

Comment: Also do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details. You need to provide the relevant part of the implementation of the ```simulation.run()```.

Comment: The main idea that I need to run this code which builds by python language in MATLAB reinforcement learning when the inputs of this code store in JSON file

Comment: Have you checked that the actual contents of `json_data` is what you expect before you pass it to the `run` method? What happens if you try to call `run` at the Python prompt rather than inside this function?